# How to speed up Redmine ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redmine

I'm testing Redmine out, and I've found that with 500,000 issues a few pages have slowed to a crawl. The two culprits are:

projects/project-name (8 seconds)

projects/project-name/issues (101 seconds)

These are the main page for the project, and the list of issues page. Obviously the issue list is beyond usable. In both cases Views only take a handful of milliseconds (20 and 60, respectively) and ActiveRecord takes the rest.

The computer this is running on should be doing fine with this, my guess is Redmine is doing more work the more items in the DB, though it should be doing the same amount of work regardless because the selects are limited.

Any tips on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I periodically run the below (+- 100,000 tickets in db) on the underlying MySQL DB:

```
    optimize table attachments
    ;optimize table auth_sources
    ;optimize table boards
    ;optimize table changes
    ;optimize table changeset_parents
    ;optimize table changesets
    ;optimize table changesets_issues
    ;optimize table comments
    ;optimize table custom_fields
    ;optimize table custom_fields_projects
    ;optimize table custom_fields_roles
    ;optimize table custom_fields_trackers
    ;optimize table custom_values
    ;optimize table documents
    ;optimize table enabled_modules
    ;optimize table enumerations
    ;optimize table groups_users
    ;optimize table issue_categories
    ;optimize table issue_relations
    ;optimize table issue_statuses
    ;optimize table issues
    ;optimize table journal_details
    ;optimize table journals
    ;optimize table member_roles
    ;optimize table members
    ;optimize table messages
    ;optimize table news
    ;optimize table open_id_authentication_associations
    ;optimize table open_id_authentication_nonces
    ;optimize table projects
    ;optimize table projects_trackers
    ;optimize table queries
    ;optimize table queries_roles
    ;optimize table repositories
    ;optimize table roles
    ;optimize table schema_migrations
    ;optimize table settings
    ;optimize table time_entries
    ;optimize table tokens
    ;optimize table trackers
    ;optimize table user_preferences
    ;optimize table users
    ;optimize table versions
    ;optimize table watchers
    ;optimize table wiki_content_versions
    ;optimize table wiki_contents
    ;optimize table wiki_pages
    ;optimize table wiki_redirects
    ;optimize table wikis
    ;optimize table workflows
```

Comment: As an added (for my own benefit also), I found an article on redmine.org that relates some interesting reasons for performance bottlenecks.   REF: http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/39100.  For the sake of expanding here, it refers to asynchronous mail notifications, number of members and number of sub-projects in affecting performance.

Comment: It helped marginally, but didn't make a significant improvement. I ended up making changes to the code itself for the sake of performance (targeting recursive methods in particular). That was met with significantly more success, but I'd only recommend it to someone familiar with Ruby. I'll accept though so this question can be closed.

Comment: @Dave - Thanks.  You may also be interested in http://www.juhavehnia.com/2015/05/using-ssds-to-improve-mysql-performance.html .  Our servers guys can't do it, as our full SAN SSD is provisions for MSSQL, but it is an option if you can.